# How to set font-size and font-family for the following html code for horizontal scroller?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code for my horizontal scroll bar. I have been able to enter text but can't figure out how to change font-size and font-family:

```html
<div id="left_upper2">
       <div class="links_body1">
            <div class="items">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100/bb0000/ffffff&text=Help"/>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100/00274c/ffcb05&text=Me"/>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100/bb0000/ffffff&text=Please"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What element do you need to edit?

Comment: given the information, I cannot make heads or tails about the question. Please clarify the question before you start getting downvotes

Comment: @Efog Sorry, I would like to edit the text component of the <img> tag.

Comment: @Sai Sorry, I would like to edit the text component of the <img> tag.

Comment: Its a place holder service - that temporarily generate something to fill a space in your site until you have your real content. It's provided to allow you to build the site whilst you wait for your actual content. Why worry about the font that the image is generated with - you'll be replacing it anyway - won't you ???

Answer (score 1):

Correct [placehold.it url](http://placehold.it/) with text size can be seen if you paste the 'clean' url (e.g. http://placehold.it/WIDTHxHEIGHT/foreground/background?text=blah) into a browser -- it'll redirect you to what actually serves the image, with all of the parameters listed; specifically, you want the `txtsize` parameter.  There doesn't appear to be one for the font family though.

https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=120&txtclr=3498db&bg=9b59b6&txt=My+Flat+Test+Image&w=480&h=600&txttrack=0

Comment: I want this too!  It makes my text too small.  There is another service called place-hold.it that takes a font size paramter, but the rest of the syntax isn't as pretty...

http://place-hold.it/200&text=200x+Foobar&fontsize=24

Answer (score 0):

@CodeUniquely I ultimately did change the structure of my horizontal scroll and yes i was just using the generated image as a placeholder. The following is what I went with:

```
<div id="left_upper2">
       <div class="links_body1">
            <div class="items">
                <div class="scroll"><span5><img src="images.png" /></span5><span4><br />content</span4></div>
                <div class="scroll"><span7><img src="images.png" /></span7><span6><br />content</span6></div>
                <div class="scroll"><span5><img src="images.png" /></span5><span4><br />content</span4></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.scroll {
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 19px;
}

.scroll span4 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.scroll span5 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
}
.scroll span6 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.scroll span7 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #00274c;
}

.scroll img {
    height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.items {    
    width: 1200px;
    -webkit-animation: hscroll 20s infinite;
    -moz-animation: hscroll 20s infinite;
    -ms-animation: hscroll 20s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hscroll {
    0%   { margin-left: 0; }
    27.33%  { margin-left: 0 }
    33.33%  { margin-left: -300px; }
    60.66% { margin-left: -300px; }
    66.66% { margin-left: -600px; }
    94.99% { margin-left: -600px; }
    100%  { margin-left: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hscroll {
    0%   { margin-left: 0; }
    27.33%  { margin-left: 0 }
    33.33%  { margin-left: -300px; }
    60.66% { margin-left: -300px; }
    66.66% { margin-left: -600px; }
    94.99% { margin-left: -600px; }
    100%  { margin-left: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hscroll {
    0%   { margin-left: 0; }
    27.33%  { margin-left: 0 }
    33.33%  { margin-left: -300px; }
    60.66% { margin-left: -300px; }
    66.66% { margin-left: -600px; }
    94.99% { margin-left: -600px; }
    100%  { margin-left: 0 }
}


.links_body1  {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;    
}
```